# CollectionView Grouping Binding the "GroupName" with "ItemTemplate"

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping) and it works fine.
but when trying to (bind) add the "GroupName" on each Item, it's not working.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location{ get; set; }
}

public class AnimalGroup : List<Animal>
{
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }

    public AnimalGroup(string groupName, List<Animal> animals) : base(animals)
    {
        GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" IsGrouped="True">

            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="0,10,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Location}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Code behind

```
public List<AnimalGroup> Animals { get; private set; } = new List<AnimalGroup>();

        public AnimalPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            Animals.Add(new AnimalGroup("Bears", new List<Animal>
            {
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "American Black Bear",
                    Location = "North America",
                },
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "Asian Black Bear",
                    Location = "Asia",
                },
            }));

            Animals.Add(new AnimalGroup("Monkeys", new List<Animal>
            {
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "Baboon",
                    Location = "Africa & Asia",
                },
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "Capuchin Monkey",
                    Location = "Central & South America",
                },
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "Blue Monkey",
                    Location = "Central and East Africa",
                },
            }));

            collectionView.ItemsSource = Animals;
        }
```

It works fine, but I want to show the "Name", "Details", **and the "GroupName"**.
(Without adding another property on the Animal class.)

I tried `<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>`
If we can do it through xaml it will be great.

just and extra note... I also want to remove "location" for specific GroupName.
for example, all the items in the GroupName "Cats", will not show "Location".

Thank you so much

Comment: Not possible. There is no binding that can get from an animal to the group it is in. You’ll have to add something to each animal. You could add an `AnimalGroup Group` to each Animal, set that to its group, then `Group.GroupName` to display that.

Comment: As @ToolmakerSteve pointed out, an `Animal` doesn't know anything about the `AnimalGroup`, it doesn't hold a reference to it. Therefore you cannot do what you're asking without modifying the `Animal` class.